# Continuity and differentiability on piecewise function

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, continuity

> Let $$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2-3, & x<0;\\-3, & x\geq 0.\end{cases}$$
>
> (a) Find the value of $x$ where $f$ is discontinuous
> (b) Find the value of $x$ where $f$ is non-differentiable

I know that the answers to (a) and (b) are NONE. But, could you please explain this so that I understand it better? Does the second condition, $(-3, \;\; x\geq0)$ redefine the first domain of the piecewise function, $(x^2-3,\;\;x<0)$?

Thanks

Comment: You should only check the point $x=0$ by using the definition of derivative at $x=0$ you'll see that it is zero at that point. It is already differentiable for the points other than zero. Also differentiability implies continuity of the function at the point under question.

Comment: @user40615 OK, so if my $x$ value was for example, $2$ instead of $0$, I would check if the function is differentiable at $2$? Why is it differentiable at $0$ if $x^2-3$ doesn't exist at $0$, since it is an open interval? thank you.

Comment: remember the definition of the derivative. when $x=2$ your formula is just a constant function $f(x)=-3$.

Comment: @user40615 I am just confused about the open interval part of this problem, what difference does it make if it's open or closed? if it's $x \leq 0$ rather than $x<0$ thanks

Comment: Points for $x<0$ your function is polynomial function which is differentiable everywhere, so there is no problem, while points for $x>0$, it is a constant function, which is diff. everywhere too. The only thing to check the continuity and diff. at zero from the right and left of zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only place we need to worry about continuity/differentiability is when $x=0$, because on each of the intervals $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$, $f$ is equal to a single polynomial function (both $x^2-3$ and $-3$ are polynomials), and so it is continuous and differentiable on those intervals. On the other hand, in any open interval about $x=0$, the function $f$ is not a polynomial, so we have check it from the definition here.

Note that $f(0)=-3$, $$\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to0^-}x^2-3=-3,$$ and $$\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to0^+}-3=-3,$$ which shows that $f$ is continuous at $x=0$.

Also:

$$\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{-3-(-3)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0^+}0=0$$

and

$$\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{(0+h)^2-3-(-3)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{h^2}{h}=\lim_{h\to0^-}h=0$$

Therefore
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=0$$

so, since $f$ is continuous at 0, and this limit exists, $f$ is also differentiable at 0.